# Firefox 26 on Windows 7 SP1 doesn't reset codeigniter session cookies

Tags: windows, codeigniter, firefox, cookies, session-cookies

When a user logs into our site, a cookie gets set like so:

```
$this->input->set_cookie(self::AUTH_COOKIE, 'v1='.$var1.'&v2='.$var2, '1814400', ".oursite.com", "/", "", FALSE);
```

When they log out, the cookie is 'unset' like so:

***----- UPDATED -----***

```
$carray = array(
    'name'   => self::AUTH_COOKIE,
    'value'  => null,
    'expire' => time() - 86500,
    'domain' => '.oursite.com',
    'path'   => '/',
    'prefix' => '',
    'secure' => FALSE
);
$this->input->set_cookie($carray);

delete_cookie(self::AUTH_COOKIE, ".oursite.com", "/", "");
```

***----- END UPDATE -----***

This works fine on most browser/platform combinations, but in Firefox 26 on Windows 7 SP1, the cookie never gets updated. It retains the data that was set when it was created.  Any idea why this approach would not work in Firefox on Windows?

***----- Additional update - this no longer works on Firefox on my Mac and also fails on Internet Explorer. Haven't tested Safari or Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this with a potentially 3-part solution. Honestly I do not know whether steps 1 & 2 are necessary as they did not work on their own, but I do not wish to mess with my code now that it seems to be working.

1. I changed the expire value of the cookie array to null.
2. I unset a second cookie called sap_r that was set if the user had clicked 'Remember Me' when logging in.
3. My original code contained an ajax call immediately after setting the cookie values to null. I switched the order so that the ajax is called first and then the cookies are 'unset'.

I tested after each of these and it was after this final step that the cookies were successfully removed. So - I do not know if some combination of the three solved it or only the last one.  If I get a chance to test further, I will comment here.

Answer (score 0):

cfr. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html:

- To delete a cookie set it with the expiration blank.
- For site-wide cookies regardless of how your site is requested, add your URL to the domain starting with a period, like this: .your-domain.com

the dot "." is missing in front of oursite.com:
.oursite.com
I think this last thing might be causing it.

If all else fails try with native PHP cookies to see whether that works.

Comment: Sorry to take so long to respond.  Yes - the dot was missing in my example, but it WAS in the actual code. I've updated my questions accordingly. I have also added the code I am trying to use to unset the cookie.